# Groovy generator error!

Tags: ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The *desktop* and *desktop-full* generators,

http://packages.ros.org/web/rosinstall/generate/raw/groovy/desktop
http://packages.ros.org/web/rosinstall/generate/raw/groovy/desktop-full

both return errors when I try to access them. In the web browser I get a long debug page with an HTTP Error 404, and running `wstool init -j8 src <generator url>` from the command line as part of the install install process gives an HTTP Error 500;

> ERROR in config: Is not a local file, nor able to download as a URL [http://packages.ros.org/web/rosinstall/generate/raw/groovy/desktop-full]: HTTP Error 500: INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

What's going on here? I'm pretty sure this just started happening. Is there a workaround? Can we fix this ASAP please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56515/groovy-generator-error!/) by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 161 on 2013-02-27

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2013-02-27**:
I sent an email about this to ros-users a little while ago.

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-02-27**:
@Dan Lazewatsky: Good stuff. Unfortunately I need it to get fixed before I can continue with testing really...

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-02-27**:
I wonder if there are caches anywhere for the meanwhile...

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2013-02-27**:
You should be able to point wstool to a local rosinstall. If you're following the wiki instructions exactly, it'll be at ~/ros_catkin_ws/src/.rosinstall.

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-02-27**:
Thanks. I'll give that a go!

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-02-27**:
@Dan Lazewatsky: Unfortunately it seems to generate a LOT of errors: http://pastie.org/pastes/6351471/text -- I wonder if this is independent.

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2013-02-27**:
I'm surprised you didn't come up against that before. There's a question on here somewhere that I can't find with a solution. Basically, just go into the src dir, and do rm -rf tf2*, and you should be able to continue.

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-02-27**:
@Dan Lazewatsky: There's also errors processing catkin, roslib, opencv, and others if you notice. Are these normal too? They weren't for me when I first did it: https://gist.github.com/alexreg/4965426 -- It was me that posted that question in fact, then you posted a duplicate and I redirected you :)

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2013-02-27**:
Those look like they're all tf2 related. You should be able to get rid of tf2* from your src dir and continue on with the install. I think despite the errors, it will still download everything else you need.

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-02-27**:
Well see the last few lines of http://pastie.org/pastes/6351471/text -- surely the catkin/roslib ones are nothing to do with tf2?? I didn't get those previously, as you can see.

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-02-27**:
Odd. I just ran again and only the opencv2 and tf2 ones remain now. Oh well. What do you get?

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-02-27**:
@Dan Lazewatsky: No luck trying to change the compiler. Either cmake ignores it, or goes into an infinite loop... *sigh*. Why did the developers choose to use something as convoluted and messy as cmake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The 404 errors should be fixed.  There seems to be an issue with reliably querying github for backend information.  If you get errors like:

```
Failed to read package.xml file from url 'https://raw.github.com/ros-gbp/vision_opencv-release/release/groovy/cv_bridge/1.10.6-0/package.xml'
```

Please just try again.  We'll work on becoming more robust with caching in the future.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-03-01**:
Thanks. That's good to know.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-03-01**:
Glad to help.  Please accept the answer using the checkmark so others don't try to answer it for you as well.

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-03-01**:
Oh, I already did. Seems it didn't register though. Darn AJAX stuff playing up. :)

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-03-01**:
I just added a better error message now too, so you don't get a traceback. The wstool will still get 500 errors if it fails though.